# sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats reset

Tags: sql-server, dmv

I want to get stats from the [sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701.aspx) view.

When I check the records from months ago, I see that after a point of time its stats reset daily, but there have been no server resets.

It seems there is a job running that makes this view reset. Can anyone help me with this problem? What kind of procedures will reset these views?

Answer (score 2):

[From the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701.aspx)

> The view returns one row for each cached stored procedure plan, and the lifetime of the row is as long as the stored procedure remains cached. When a stored procedure is removed from the cache, the corresponding row is eliminated from this view.

This dmv is therefore reset for each stored procedure recompile, which can happen, for example, after index and statistics maintenance